# ZXing scanning of multiple barcode

Tags: ios, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've found this library https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC which is a port of ZXing to Objective-C and supports multiple barcode scanning. I need that for an App so I've tried to get it worked but it doesn't detect anything when I pass an image with multiple barcodes
Here's the code I'm using

```
CGImageRef imageToDecode = self.imgn.image.CGImage;  // Given a CGImage in which we are looking for barcodes

    ZXLuminanceSource* source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc] initWithCGImage:imageToDecode] autorelease];
    ZXBinaryBitmap* bitmap = [ZXBinaryBitmap binaryBitmapWithBinarizer:[ZXHybridBinarizer binarizerWithSource:source]];

    NSError* error = nil;

    ZXDecodeHints* hints = [ZXDecodeHints hints];


    ZXMultiFormatReader* reader = [ZXMultiFormatReader reader];
    ZXGenericMultipleBarcodeReader* multi = [[ZXGenericMultipleBarcodeReader alloc] initWithDelegate:reader];
   NSArray * result = [multi decodeMultiple:bitmap hints:hints error:&error];
```

This returns a nil array and error contains the "no barcodes found" error. When I use the MultiFormatReader with just one barcode it's OK, but when I add a picture with more than one of the same barcode, well recognized with MultiFormatReader it doesn't detect anything
Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Actually if there's any other free iOS barcode library which can read multiple barcodes from an image it would be great too

Comment: Did you find any library .? That can read multiple QR codes..one after the another ?

Answer (score 1):

It took 4 months to get reviewed but a fix for this is already on master.

+info: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/pull/235

Comment: I am not able to able access the github link